# Keyboard shortuct on Mac

Tags: macos, mac

I am new to both Mac OSX and iPhone development. Coming from Windows and mostly use keyboard shortcuts to open windows/applications etc. As many of you know doing an alt + F opens the File menu [drop down], does there exists a similar keyboard shortuct so that we can make a drop down and then subsequently select a submenu using arrow keys. I am looking for a way as not each and every submenu does have a keyboard shortcut.

Can anybody tell this beginner. I have searched a lot about keyboard shortcuts but none shows the way I want to use the keyboard.

Thanks
Arnieterm

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a Mac to test this on at the moment, but [this page](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1343) says that hitting Control-F2 "moves focus to the menu bar." Perhaps this is what you're looking for.

Take a look through that web page. It's got tons of Mac OS keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: I have confirmed that this does actually work.

Comment: This shortcut can be disabled. Check the “Keyboard Navigation” subtree in “Keyboard & Mouse” > “Keyboard Shortcuts” in *System Preferences*.

Answer (score 0):

ctrl+f2 i believe lets you navigate through the main menu bar of the active application.